# Updating multiple database rows in Spring - Mybatis

Tags: spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to update multiple database rows. Using `mybatis 3.1` and `spring 3`
here is my update query in `mapper.xml`:

```
<update id="updateEmployeeTrips" parameterType="com.xxx.xxx.EmployeeTrip">
    <foreach collection="list" item="employeeTrips" index="index" separator=";">
        update employee_trips set pickup_drop_time = #{employeeTrips.pickupTime} where id = #{employeeTrips.id}
    </foreach>
</update>
```

Giving the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update employee_trips set pickup_drop_time = '01:35:00' where id = 10' at line 3

Comment: What are the types of `employeeTrips.pickupTime` and `pickup_drop_time`?

Comment: java.sql.Time for employeeTrips.pickupTime  and TIME for pickup_drop_time

Comment: @haihui are you there?

Comment: Hm, it's simply possible that you cannot write multiple updates after each other and do them all together. Have you tried doing the updates in that way in your SQL client?

Comment: ya it is working in my SQL Client. Using mySQL workbench

Answer (score 6):

Append the parameter `allowMultiQueries=true` to the URL of JDBC and then try this:

**mapper.xml:**

```
<update id="updateEmployeeTrips" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach collection="list" item="employeeTrips" index="index" separator=";">
        update employee_trips set pickup_drop_time = #{employeeTrips.pickupTime} where id = #{employeeTrips.id}
    </foreach>
</update>
```

**Mapper.java**

```
updateEmployeeTrips(List<employeeTrip> employeeTripList)
```